# Dynamically adding CSS class with transition-duration, visibility, and opacity not working in chrome

Tags: javascript, css, google-chrome, css-transitions

I am trying to make a transition by dynamically adding class with  `transition-duration, visibility, and opacity`. Here the `.overlay` should transition to `red` color over **1 second** after clicking show button. It works perfectly in firefox, But **not in CHROME & IE9**

```
My chrome version: 31.0.1650.63 m
```

**[FIDDLE DEMO >>](http://jsfiddle.net/sYLhq/3/)**

**HTML**

```
<div class="wrapper">
    <div class="overlay">

    </div>
</div>

<button>Show</button>
```

**CSS**

```
.wrapper {
    width: 500px;
    height: 100px;
    background-color: black;
}

.overlay {
    background-color: red;
    width: 100%; 
    height: 100%;
    visibility: hidden;
    opacity: 0;
}

.show {
    visibility: visible;
    opacity: 1;
    transition-duration: 1s;
}
```

**SCRIPT**

```
document.querySelector('button').addEventListener('click', function() {
    document.querySelector('.overlay').classList.add('show');
});
```

Comment: Seems like a bug in the browser if you ask me, you should submit a bug report to the Chrome team. However your example works if you remove the `visibility` property: http://jsfiddle.net/sYLhq/5/

Comment: @JonKoops But it will not work in FF if visibility is removed.

Comment: It works for me on chrome when you run it as a standalone page , but when it runs from **jsfiddle** seems to be a bug.

My chrome version is **31.0.1650.63 m** too.

Comment: IE9 doesn’t support CSS transitions.

Comment: @HectorWilliam You are rite! It works for me when it made standalone. So actually where is the problem? In chrome or fiddle.

Comment: Bug is on **jsfiddle**  ... In this case the bug is originated when **jsfiddle** try to excecute **transition-duration:** , I guess **jsfiddle** isn't handling it,that only works on firefox.

Answer (score 0):

You can use for Transition:

```
-webkit-transition-duration: 1s;
```

Comment: Vendor-prefixed declarations aren’t required since Chrome 26.